# Use Specific Key from Multidimensional PHP Array As Javascript Variable Jquery onClick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, var

I have a multi-dimensional PHP array where the key for each inner array is an ID of button I will be clicking and instantiating a jQuery function.

I basically want to dynamically create a javascript VAR array from that PHP array based on the Id that is clicked. Here is the array:

```
$ContentGroupIds = array(
    43 => array( 511, 531, 567 ),
    54 => array( 483, 499, 509 )
);
```

So you can see I have `ContentGroupId's: 43 and 54` which each point to an array of `ContentId's`.

When I click on the button for `ContentGroupId = 43`, I need to dynamically set the jquery var to look like this:

```
var contentids = ['511','531','567'];
```

Then I can use that `var` in the rest of my jquery function.

Comment: this not a valid PHP code

Comment: Ok bro @MarcinOrlowski you get the idea, I was trying to illustrate more clearly. thx for dnvt.

Comment: I'm assuming the inner array keys are expected to be keys, rather than the index?  Or are the inner most arrays, true arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the ContentGroupID's as an attribute on your buttons (having your HTML output would help), and grab that attribute with jQuery.

## PHP/HTML:

```
<?php
    $ContentGroupIds = array(
        43 => array( 511, 531, 567 ),
        54 => array( 483, 499, 509 )
    );

    foreach( $ContentGroupIds as $item => $ids ){
        // Convert ID Array to string
        $attr = implode( ',', $ids );

        // Output: <a href="#" class="btn" attr-ids="511,531,567">Button #43</a>
        echo '<a href="#" class="btn" attr-ids="'. $attr .'">Button #'. $item .'</a>';
    }
?>
```

## jQuery:

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn', function(){
    var str = $(this).attr('attr-ids'),  // str = "511,531,567"
        arr = str.split(',');     // arr = ['511','531','567']

    console.log(arr); // (3) [0:"511", 1:"531", 2:"567"]
});
```

## Functional Snippet:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.btn', function(){
    var str = $(this).attr('attr-ids'),
        arr = str.split(',');

    alert(arr);
});
```

```css
/*CSS only to make the links more buttony*/a{display:inline-block;background:#0095ff;padding: 6px 18px;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;border:1px solid #07c;box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 #66bfff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:14px border-radius:3px;}a:hover{background: #0085ee;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn" attr-ids="511,531,569">Button #43</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" attr-ids="483,499,509">Button #54</a>
```

Comment: Thx @Xhynk. Good call, I thought about something like this after a few hours. I will go with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a php array into javascript json using php *json_encode*

Comment: Yes @klesper but how to ONLY get the array for the specific key when I click the corresponding button?